# Is there a way to convert non-ascii chars to unicode and leave ascii as they are?

Tags: java, unicode, encoding, uri, apache-httpclient-4.x

I've just found out, that apache httpclient returns incorrectly decoded location header, if it contains percent encoded letters.

[image]

when the same request in browser returns correct string:

[image]

I've written a method for restoring uri. Did I write it right? Is there a simplier way?

```
import java.net.URLDecoder;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String uri = "/search-zero?searchterm=\u00D1\u008C";
        String converted = convert(uri);
        System.out.println(converted); // /search-zero?searchterm=%D1%8C
        System.out.println(URLDecoder.decode(converted, "utf-8")); // /search-zero?searchterm=ь
    }

    private static String convert(String uri) {
        char[] chars = uri.toCharArray();
        int i = 0;
        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
        while (i < chars.length) {
            int n = (int) chars[i];
            if (n > 127) {
                result.append('%');
                result.append(String.format("%02X", n));
            } else {
                result.append(chars[i]);
            }
            i++;
        }
        return result.toString();
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**

My current HttpClient configuration:

```
@Bean
public CloseableHttpClient getHttpClient() {
    ConnectionConfig connectionConfig = ConnectionConfig.custom().setCharset(Consts.UTF_8).build();

    PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager cm = new PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager();
    cm.setMaxTotal(200);
    cm.setDefaultMaxPerRoute(20);

    return HttpClients.custom()
            .setDefaultConnectionConfig(connectionConfig)
            .setConnectionManager(cm)
            .setRedirectStrategy(new CustomRedirectStrategy())
            .build();
}

public class CustomRedirectStrategy extends DefaultRedirectStrategy {

    @Override
    public URI getLocationURI(HttpRequest request, HttpResponse response, HttpContext context) throws ProtocolException {
        System.out.println(response.getFirstHeader("location"));
        URI uri = super.getLocationURI(request, response, context);
        return uri;
    }
}
```

**WORKING CODE (WE NEEDED EITHER CORRECTLY SET UP CUSTOM CONNECTION MANAGER OR JUST DELETE IT) THANKS OLEG!!**

```
    @Bean
    public CloseableHttpClient getHttpClient() {
        ConnectionConfig connectionConfig = ConnectionConfig.custom().setCharset(Consts.UTF_8).build();

//        PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager cm = new PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager();
//        cm.setMaxTotal(200);
//        cm.setDefaultMaxPerRoute(20);

        return HttpClients.custom()
                .setDefaultConnectionConfig(connectionConfig)
//                .setConnectionManager(cm)
                .setRedirectStrategy(new CustomRedirectStrategy())
                .build();
    }
```

Comment: To encode, or to decode?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch, I need to convert `searchterm=\u00D1\u008C` to `searchterm=%D1%8C`

Comment: Where is you testing output?  Don't ask us whether your program works: ask the run-time system!  If you don't get the expected output, then you have an issue to bring to us.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One can force HttpClient to use a non-standard charset for protocol elements, which should improve inter-operability with broken web servers that include unescaped non-ASCII chars in 'Location' headers

```
ConnectionConfig connectionConfig = ConnectionConfig.custom()
        .setCharset(Consts.ISO_8859_1)
        .build();
CloseableHttpClient client = HttpClients.custom()
        .setDefaultConnectionConfig(connectionConfig)
        .build();
```

Comment: hi! It seems to be the right answer, but unfortunately after I made suggested changes I still get the same exeption. I tried all charsets (UTF_8, ASCII, ISO_8859_1) but Location always `Location: /search-zero?searchterm=Ñ?`     I've also added my httpclient configuration to question post

Comment: A-HA! I removed `setCommectionManages(cm)` from my code and it worked with UTF-8! Added working code to question